# Is there a better way to 'do nothing' in javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript

My url looks like this = `https://studentscafe.com/menu/2`

I'm trying to check whether or not it has 2 different url params...

1.) `?dinner=1`

or

2.) `&dinner=1`

If #1 is present, do nothing

If #2 is present, do nothing

But if neither are present, default to adding `?dinner=1` to the url.

Is there a better way to have a  default do nothing in an if statement? [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jQu3L/56/) for example.

```
var path = 'https://studentscafe.com/menu/2';

if (path.indexOf('?dinner=1') >= 1) {
    console.log('has ?');
    // do nothing leave url as it is

} else {
    console.log('does not have ?');
    if (path.indexOf('&dinner=1') >= 1) {
        // do nothing leave url as it is
    } else {
        path = path + '?dinner=1';
    }
}
```

Expected output: if the url doesn't have #1 or #2: `https://studentscafe.com/menu/2?dinner=1`

Comment: Instead of doing nothing, just negate the condition and lose the `else` block:  `if (path.indexOf('?dinner=1') < 1) { ... }`  - You may also want to make note that `indexOf` can return `0` if the substring is found in the first position (index 0), and so `>= 1` should probably be `>= 0`.

Comment: Best would be to use <=-1 as the condition

Comment: If that's in response to my comment, the negation of my suggested `>= 0` would be `< 0`, which is identical to `<= -1` in the given context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the `!` negation operator, this can be rather simple:

```js
var path = 'https://studentscafe.com/menu/2';

if (!/[?&]dinner=1/.test(path)) {
    path += '?dinner=1';
}

console.log(path);
```

Answer (score 16):

Instead of

```
if (something) {
    // do nothing 
} else {
    // do what you need
}
```

You can use

```
if (!something) {
    // do what you need
}
```

In your case:

```
if (path.indexOf('?dinner=1') == -1 && path.indexOf('&dinner=1') == -1) {
    path = path + '?dinner=1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

```
var path = 'https://studentscafe.com/menu/2';

// Since there is no change to path if it contains either ?dinner=1 or &dinner=1

if (path.indexOf('dinner=1') >= 1) {
    console.log('has dinner');
    // do nothing leave url as it is

} else {
   path = path + '?dinner=1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern JS you may simply do like

```
['?dinner=1','?dinner=2'].every(s => !path.includes(s)) && (path += '?dinner=1');
```